# durandaljs 2.0 navigation

Tags: durandal, single-page-application

I have a view with pagination. When the user clicks on a page number, I display the data for that page.

I only want the data items to be replaced so I don't want to navigate to the "next page." So what I'm doing is using the router.navigate(url, { replace: false, trigger: false }); to add the page to the browser's history, but not to trigger the navigate there.

If after I get the data, I click on the browser's back button, the URL changes to the previous one, but I don't get an event. If once I'm back in the previous page, I click the browser's forward button, I get the trigger event from that page.

Example. I'm at /# and it is displaying page 1 of the data. The user click on the "next page" link on the page. I display page 2's data, and I replace the url with /#welcome/2 Now if I click on the browser's back button the URL changes back to /# but the page doesn't trigger. If I press the browser's forward button the URL changes back to /#welcome/2 and the page triggers. Now that that has happened, I can click the back button and page one will trigger; and I can go back and forth between page 1 and page 2. If the user clicks on "page 3", the problem happens again.

If you all need a working example, I will deploy it, but currently this is only running on my local box.

Comment: don't be afraid of jsfiddle.net :) but I don't think it's necessary for this example, you're pretty clear

Comment: I deployed a sample of what's happening. http://webf1durandalpaginationtest.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

IMO paging, like sorting/filtering represent the internal state of a view/widget and shouldn't be presented via routes. Consider e.g. user is on `#something/3` and bookmarks the url. After deleting a couple of items there's no `#something/3` any longer and the bookmark fails. Here's some more thought food on that topic http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/03/stop-using-backbone-as-if-it-were-a-stateless-web-server/

**Update** based on comments:

`activate` on hitting browser back get's not called for two reason. a) welcome.js returns a singleton  and b) in shell.html viewCache is set to true. When the user press browser forward it get's called because at this time route `#welcome/2` from the SPA perspective is called the first time, so `activate` kicks in.

One way to make the system work would be to force every page change (regardless if it was initialized by SPA  or browser) running through `activate`. Here are the required steps: Convert the singleton into a constructor, set cacheViews: false and replace click events by normal hrefs that calls the page route.

**Update 2**
Here's an example that combines the inPage navigation (without router involvement) with the ability to use browser back/forth navigation. `init` is responsible for setting up things that are common for `activate` and `gotoPage`.

### Viewmodel

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout'], function( router, ko ) {

    var ctor = function() {
        this.pageNo = ko.observable();
        this.pageData = ko.observable();
    };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function( page ) {
        this.init(page);
    };

    ctor.prototype.init = function( page ) {
        this.pageNo(page || 1);
        this.pageData('Data for ' + this.pageNo());
    };

    ctor.prototype.gotoPage = function( page ) {
        var url = "extras/welcome/" + page;
        this.init(page);
        router.navigate(url, { replace: false, trigger: false });
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

### View

```
<section>
    <h1>
        Hello Durandal Pagination
    </h1>
    <a data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 1)" style="cursor: pointer;">Page 1</a>
    <a data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 2)" style="cursor: pointer;">Page 2</a>
    <a data-bind="click: gotoPage.bind($data, 3)" style="cursor: pointer;">Page 3</a>

    <h2 data-bind="text: pageData"></h2>
</section>
```

Live example at: http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#extras/welcome

Comment: Yes, I would normally agree with you on that. However, on the site that I'm working on, it is a good idea. Regardless of the design discussion, the question still remains. Am I doing something wrong with my code? Or is there something broken in durandal? Or is it working as designed?

Comment: Try using simple hrefs like `<a href="#/welcome/1" style="cursor: pointer;">Page 1</a>`. No reason for `doData` simply activate the correct page in `activate`.

Comment: That will not call the router.navigate(url, { replace: false, trigger: false }); which is the whole point.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did thing last night about the cache, but that alone doesn't fix the problem. 
I see what you have done and this still doesn't achieve what I want.

Comment: Pressed the 'Add Comment' too soon. Here is my entire reply: Thanks for the update. I did think last night about the cache, but that alone doesn't fix the problem. 
I see what you have done and this still doesn't achieve what I want. In your example when you click on the links only the data changes, same as mine. When you navigate you see the entire view refresh. As I mentioned I didn't want the entire view to refresh. What you have done can also be achieved by changing to trigger: true. So I can do your solution and only get the full view refresh sometimes, or just do trigger: true

Comment: I might decide to do the simplified version of the solution "trigger: true" or simply change the page link like in your comment for this particular view. But I can see your solution working in many other scenarios I have in mind. Thank you very much for the solution together.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting in the original example I put together. If when I first load the page, I click on page 2 and then try to go back to page 1, it doesn't work. But if I click on page 2 and then click on page 3, when I try to go back to page 2 it works. It works too if I go back as far as page 1. And from then on navigation works. (Going back meaning clicking the back button on the browser.) It also works if I first click on page 2 and then click on page 1. From then on browser navigation works. Going to try a few more things here and see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: simply set a break point in `activate`. When changing this from internally this won't be hit. When forcing a change from the outside back/forth browser button it will run. Combine that with cacheViews:true and once all possible pages are cached there's no need any longer to call activate.

Comment: If I follow the steps where I click on page 2 and then 3 before I start navigation with the browser button, activate always gets hit as I navigate even though cache is set to true in the original example. And yes, you are right, activate won't get hit when the navigation is internal.